# aspnet_compiler is not working in windows 2019 server but works on windows 10 pro

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspnet-compiler

I am trying to use aspnet_compiler.exe to compile a webapp project. While doing that I am getting error in windows 2019 server (has .net framework 4.8.03761) but it compiles fine on windows 10 pro ( .net framework 4.8.04084).

In aspx file I have:

```
<asp:HtmlIframe name="docViewFrame" id="docViewFrame" runat="server"
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation">
    </asp:HtmlIframe>
```

In .cs file it is defined as:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe docViewFrame;
```

I am getting this error when I run it in windows 2019 server:

> The type or namespace name 'HtmlIframe' does not exist in the
> namespace 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)

It looks like this is happening because of the version different of .net 4.8 framework in both the machines (so the version of aspnet_compiler.exe is also slightly different). The same code works on windows 10 pro, with the same .net framework 4.8. I cannot upgrade the .net framework version in windows 2019 server.

Comment: Did you run windows update to get latest version?  Also in VS Solution Explorer compare references.  You may need to add a missing reference using the menu project : Add References.  You can open the csproj files with notepad and compare the reference versions of the HtmlControls.  The HtmlFrame reference may be missing.

Comment: Yes windows update ran on the target machine and also both the .csproj files are identical.

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  The dependencies of the compile do not recognize Net updates so the intermediate obj files probably didn't get recompiled.

Comment: Did a clean build and the problem persist. The only way I found to avoid the issue is to copy the compiler from the windows 10 machine and run it on windows 2019 server.

Comment: Why can't you update the Net Version in Widows 2019 server?  Looks like something was fixed.  Hopefully a Monthly push will fix issue when  Updates are installed.

Comment: I last updated a couple of weeks ago. If it was fixed after that then it may have been fixed. Although I doubt it. I will take a look

Comment: Did you update the drivers/dlls on the motherboard at the vendors website?  The motherboard drivers/dlls do not get updated by the Windows Updates and there are dlls that still get called by the Net Library.

Comment: I did not update the motherboard drivers as copying the aspnet_compiler.exe from another machine (that had the more recent version of the .net ) fixed the issue. I think that it is the version of asp.net compiler in server 2019 is creating the issue. I will watch out for updates from microsoft.